# .each() bind hover events and pass a variable to handler functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, each, jquery-hover

I'm trying to bind a hover event to some elements, walking through them with $.each, with the peculiarity that I want to pass a css classname as a parameter of the hover's handler functions, but it seems that the scope is not the one I'm expecting. I've tried to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $madewithLabels = $("#made-with .label");

    // Binding
    $madewithLabels.each(function (index) {
       // get bootstrap css classname for the current element in the loop
       var bsClass = getHoverClass($(this));
       console.info("css class is: " + bsClass + " - " + typeof(bsClass));

       $(this).hover(
           function (bsClass) {
               console.info(bsClass);
               $(this).addClass(bsClass);
           },
           function (bsClass) {
               console.info(bsClass);
               $(this).removeClass(bsClass);
           }
       );
    });
});
```

- 1st console.info: getHover() gets the right css class name (string) when the events are bound (on document ready)
- 2nd/3rd console.info: when hover's handler functions are executed bsClass is an object (I guess it's a jQuery one)

I've solved it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $madewithLabels = $("#made-with .label");

    // Binding
    $madewithLabels.each(function (index) {
        $(this).hover(
            function () {
                $(this).addClass(getHoverClass($(this)));
            },
            function () {
                $(this).removeClass(getHoverClass($(this)));
            }
        );
    });
});
```

But my questions are...

Is using $(this) the right solution?

Why when I pass a string variable to the handler functions I get an object when the function is called? is it because some type casting? is it because closure scope?

Thanks to the jQuery gurus answering!

Comment: I think your `function` gets 2 parameters passed to it. So it should look like this `function(index, item)`. Use the `item` one to bind your hover events. It should look like this I think: `$(item).hover...`

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting in the hover callback is an Event object, as mentioned by [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover-handlerIn-handlerOut):

> handlerIn
>
> Type: Function( Event eventObject )
>
> A function to execute when the mouse pointer enters the element.

So in your first example change:

```
function (bsClass) {
```

To this:

```
function () {
```

So you keep using the original `bsClass` that you calculated before.